# PHP still not executing on MAC OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-yosemite

I cannot get PHP to work on my computer. My browser prints out the php code rather than executing it.

The first thing I did was to open up the apache conf file and edit it to uncomment the php line

Opened file:

```
    sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

This is the line I uncommented in that file:

```
    LoadModule php_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

I then restarted apache using:

```
    sudo apachectl restart
```

Apache would run, http://127.0.0.1 would show "It works!" 
I then created a file called test.php, in which I put the following line of code:

```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

In chrome I clicked file -> open file -> test.php, and all it printed was the code I had written.

I've also tried changing the line "User _www" in the conf file to

```
    User myusername
```

I've tried changing the line "DirectoryIndex index.html" to:

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

None of these changes have resulted in PHP script executing on my computer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you install on your own, or did you install something like MAMP?

Comment: I used the built in apache and PHP. I did not install MAMP

Comment: Did you try `http://127.0.0.1/test.php`, or whatever path it is to the file?

Comment: That gives: "Not Found. The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server."

Comment: Where did you save the file?

Comment: I don't know OS X but there is a default dir to put the file like `/var/www/` or something.

Comment: myusername/Sites/test.php

Comment: Of course opening the file via File → Open will output the raw code, because that's circumventing the Apache web server entirely.

Comment: Make sure /etc/apache2/httpd.conf contains the path to test.php as `DocumentRoot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the **test.php** in **/Library/WebServer/Documents** .

Make sure you have

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

inside your test.php

Open Chrome. Go to **http://localhost/test.php**

You cant just open test.php file using Chrome. PHP script needs to be executed by a PHP Compiler before you can see any output. If you simply open the PHP file in chrome, it will show you the PHP code only.

Comment: Great Chris. Happy Hacking with PHP